# How to connect to a Windows PC from an Ubuntu terminal over the Internet?

Tags: command-line, windows, windows-10, remote-access

I want to access my Windows 10 PC over the Internet via an Ubuntu terminal. Is this possible?

(I don't want to use a remote desktop client, just the terminal.)

Comment: yes it's possible: it's also a combined Windows/Ubuntu answer, off-topic here.  Better ask at http://superuser.com